# Kentico 8.2 - Is there a way to delete Attachment History from the GUI

Tags: kentico

Our attachments have been stored in our database for a very long time, and it has caused the database to become huge and our backups to be extremely unreliable. We have moved our attachments to the file system and that shaved off a great deal of size.

Now our largest table is `CMS_AttachmentHistory`. I've been able to test brute force deleting every row in SQL (and every row in the `CMS_VersionAttachment` junction table). But is there a way to accomplish this in the Kentico Admin GUI without having to resort to this?

When I say brute force delete, I mean:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.CMS_VersionAttachment

DELETE FROM dbo.CMS_AttachmentHistory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in the GUI that will do this, but it's also going to impact the page version history.  If you go to *Settings > Content > Content management* and look in the *Workflow* section, you can see a setting named **Version history length**.  Reducing this to a lower number (I believe 20 is the default) will reduce the version history stored to reflect the new value by deleting the unneeded rows.

This will affect all version history though, not just the attachment, but also the pages themselves.  That being the case, you would need to decide if you need/want to keep the version history of the pages or not.

If you don't want to lose that history, then I'd say that a good option would be to write a script that can set the `AttachmentBinary` column to `null` for the records that you don't need/want (given that you say that you now store the files on the filesystem, any current versions will have the correct value, so this is probably all of them)

Comment: I ended up writing a plugin that does what you suggested. Rather proud of it, tbh. But thank you for the response!

Comment: The module I wrote to resolve our issue can be found at this repo: https://github.com/CityOfNewOrleans/KenticoSpringCleaningModule

Comment: Looks interesting, I may have to check that out :)

Comment: Just to add to what mneild said above, don't _ever_ delete all attachment history for any attachment you need. Kentico makes a dogleg through the `CMS_AttachmentHistory` table in order to load _any_ attachment. If you blanket delete all attachment history records, every last attachment will become unfindable to Kentico.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about 8.2. But you can try to experiment with `recycle bin/objects`. There are a couple topics: [topic 1](https://devnet.kentico.com/forums/f46/t21760/table-cms_attachemtnhistory-is-quite-large) and [topic 2](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/is-it-possible-to-purge-version-history-for-an-entire-site). I just check it puts there attachment every time you delete it, even though I have in setting "files on disc".  You can do like Kentico recommends set binary field to null or write script using API.

Comment: We did that already but it didn't make a dent in the size of the `CMS_AttachmentHistory` table. That alone is 33GB!

Comment: sorry I just update my answer, please read again please. It create a record every time in attachment history and there is nothing in Recycle bin.

Comment: We already tried emptying the Kentico Recycle Bin. It didn't make a difference in the size of the attachment history table. 8.2 has a very different set behaviors with regards to attachments from version 7. Neither of those articles were relevant, sorry.

Comment: Also, I can't perform a `TRUNCATE` on `CMS_AttachmentHistory` in Kentico 8.2 bc of a FK constraint. I am definitely not about to start messing with that.

Comment: yeah truncate  will not work without dropping contraints ... did you try to set to null?